# Trouble seeing background image in design view

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am working a school project in visual studio, C#. i add background image for every page at deign view; but at run time i don't see those images. 
can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please review the FAQ on the titles to use when posting. I edited your post.

Comment: I am not using any code just the design. i changed the property of each form in BackgroundImage

Comment: okay, I have 3 windows forms and i make each form have the same background image by changing in the property window of each forms.

Comment: in the design view i can see the back ground changing but when i run it there is no change of background image.

Comment: Okay, please try starting over from scratch. Since you are a beginner a bug like this could be nearly impossible to troubleshoot. Or, you could upload your project and link to it.

Comment: I am new to programming and to forums could you please tell me how i can insert image here (in this forum)?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/83374217/Picture1.png You have to click the Image Icon and browse to the file location.